# TFS2010 msbuild msdeploy Unauthorized Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, msdeploy, continuous-deployment

Appreciate any guidance or advice on below issue

I am using TFS2010 and below msbuild parameters in order to deploy build on staging server (continous deployment). I have done all necessery configuration such as

> Management Service Delegation
>
> Management Service
>
> Filesystem Permission
>
> IIS Manager Permission

msbuild parameters

```
/p:validatearchitecture=true  /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployOnbuild=True 
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=stagingserver
/p:DeployIISAppPath="cddemo" /p:UserName=username /p:Password=password 
/p:Outdir="D:\Demo\Demo\\"
```

Having below error. how to resolve it? and How can I remove https from link and use verbosity parameter to see detailed error.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0
>   \Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (3588): Web deployment task
>   failed.(Remote agent (URL 
>   `https://stagingserver:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=cddemo`) could not be
>   contacted.  Make sure the remote agent service is installed and
>   started on the target computer.) Make sure the site name, user name,
>   and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact
>   your local or server administrator. Error details: Remote agent (URL
>   `https://stagingserver:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=cddemo`) could not be
>   contacted.  Make sure the remote agent service is installed and
>   started on the target computer. An unsupported response was received.
>   The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected.
>   **The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**

Comment: Is the account the build agent is running as have local admin rights on your staging server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of two things to try:

1. Qualify your user name with the server/domain name: `/p:UserName:Server\Username`
2. Try explicitly defining `/p:AuthType=Basic` or `/p:AuthType:NTLM`

Comment: will try. How can I remove "s" from genreated https link just have http? what is verbosity parameter to see detailed error i.e stack trace

Comment: I don't believe you can, but your `AllowUntrustedCertificate` parameter should sort that out anyway.